# PHP preg_replace_callback works on 5.3 but not on 5.2.17

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

i have the following code:

```
    return preg_replace_callback("#\{gallery: '(.+?)'(?: dir: ([0-1]))?\}#i", create_function('$i', '$dir = isset( $i[2] ) ? 1 : 0; $oGallery = new Gallery( $i[1] ) ; $oGallery->PublicSide($dir);' ), $string);
```

the problem is that this works on my localhost (PHP5.3) but when i upload it to my server (5.2.17) it doesnt.. any ideas why? seems to have something to do with the single quotes on `"#\{gallery: '(.+?)'(?: dir: ([0-1]))?\}#i"`

Comment: Define "it doesn't work"? What does the function call return?

Comment: It just returns the full original string, as if it didn't find any matches in this case: {gallery: 'images/'} or {gallery: 'images/' dir: 1}

Comment: Have you read through the PHP docs of this function? It's behaviour may be different between PHP 5.3 and 5.2.x http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't actually returning anything from your callback, so it's not going to make any replacements.  Maybe you meant to do this, instead?

```
... return $oGallery->PublicSide($dir); ...
```